# Is there any way to run eclipse plug-in applications without fully start the eclipse platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

Consider a simple "Hello world" plug-in, how can I run it without having to fully launch the eclipse platform?

Comment: Why is jdt tagged? That would imply that you want to load a significant portion of the Eclipse infrastructure for handling Java code / editors.

Comment: Yes I need jdt functionalities. I exposed JDT infrastructure via OSGi servlet bundles and now it works at least~

Answer (score 1):

Since eclipse plugins are OSGi bundles you could start a simple hello-world plugin in an OSGi container like [Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/) or [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html)

[Here](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_standalone.htm)  is an example on how to start the eclipse help system standalone. (This of course as more dependencies, than hello-world)